# How to clear all pageFlowScope maps from session?

Tags: java, jsf, session-variables, myfaces, trinidad

How to clear pageFlowScopes and view caches from session when we are sure its no longer required?

Following clears `pageFlowScope` map in current request context

```
    RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    requestContext.getPageFlowScope().clear();
```

But if I dump `http-session attributes` I still see many instances of `PageFlowscopes` in the session

```
org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.PageFlowScope.ois6p8lk1 
org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.PageFlowScope.ois6p8lk2 
org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.PageFlowScope.ois6p8lk3
```

and view caches as well

```
org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.VIEW_CACHE.1qvzgdgkw
org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.VIEW_CACHE.2qvzgdgkw
org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.VIEW_CACHE.3qvzgdgkw
```

Obviously if I clear session attributes it will all go away but I don't want to do that, Is there any other way ?

Using

- trinidad-api-1.0.10.jar
- myfaces-impl-1.1.5.jar

**EDIT**

Also observed following attribute is kept in session forever, and the content grows over time

```
org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.Change
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PageFlowScope**

If not planning to use multiple pageflowscopes following entry in `trinidad-config.xml` can be altered

```
<page-flow-scope-lifetime>1</page-flow-scope-lifetime>
```

This will control number of `org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.PageFlowScope` kept in session.

---

**VIEW_CACHE**

If not planning to use `VIEW_CACHE` following `init params` in `web.xml` can be configured to a minimal value.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.CLIENT_STATE_MAX_TOKENS</param-name>
    <param-value>1</param-value>
</context-param>    

<context-param>
    <param-name>
        org.apache.myfaces.NUMBER_OF_VIEWS_IN_SESSION
    </param-name>
    <param-value>1</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This will keep control over number of  `org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.VIEW_CACHE` kept in session

---

**trinidadinternal.Change**

I couldn't find a way to to avoid this.

---

Ended up using following method to cleanup

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static Map<String, Object> getSessionMap() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
}


private void clearMyfacesSessionAttributes() {
    RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    requestContext.getPageFlowScope().clear();
    Map<String, Object> sessionMap = getSessionMap();
    Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> entrySet = sessionMap.entrySet();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : entrySet) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        if(key.contains("org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.VIEW_CACHE")
                || key.contains("org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.PageFlowScope")
                || key.contains("org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.Change"))
        {
            sessionMap.remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```